# Does the latest elasticsearch 7.x support scrolling across clusters in different nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

Ok so the situation is that we have two clusters within our solution of elastic search, one on one node and one on another. If the platform is setup with a round robin approach, will the scrolling API working in this situation or will it get confused ? It seems to work for the first scroll but the second fails with search_context_missing_exception, leading me to believe that this is a problem with the round robin run the scroll request across multiple clusters and/or node. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling API creates a persistent search context that will stay around until you're done scrolling, or you clear the search context or the search times out.

However, that search context cannot be shared across two different clusters, so if you start a scrolling search on one cluster you need to perform it entirely on the same cluster without switching clusters. So the round robin approach will be a problem here.

However, if the two clusters are exact replicas of each other, you might be able to use [`search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after) instead. Using this approach is also recommended instead of the more heavyweight and costly scrolling API.